# Swift: How does zip() handle two different sized collections?

Tags: swift, swift2

The zip() function takes two sequences and returns a sequence of tuples following:

```
output[i] = (sequence1[i], sequence2[i])
```

However, the sequences can potentially be of different dimensions. My question is how does the Swift language deal with this?

[The docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_StandardLibrary_Functions/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/func/s:FSs3zipu0_Rq_Ss12SequenceTypeq0_S__FTq_q0__GVSs12Zip2Sequenceq_q0__) were utterly useless.

Seems to me, there are two possibilities (in Swift):

- Stop at end of the shortest
- Stop at end of longest, filling with default constructor or a predefined value for shorter's element type

Comment: The second option would be difficult because a type need not have a default constructor or a "predefined value".

Comment: @MartinR Good point. I suppose using protocols and generics you could assert the template's implementation of a protocol that assert's the existence of a default constructor.

Comment: the predefined value is called .none.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Swift uses the first option, **the resulting sequence will have a length equal to the shorter of the two inputs**.

For example:

```
let a: [Int] = [1, 2, 3]
let b: [Int] = [4, 5, 6, 7]

let c: [(Int, Int)] = zip(a, b) // [(1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Apple's `zip(_:_:)` documentation has since been updated to answer this question:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/1541125-zip

> If the two sequences passed to `zip(_:_:)` are different lengths, the resulting sequence is the **same length as the shorter sequence**. In this example, the resulting array is the same length as `words`:
>
> ```
> let words = ["one", "two", "three", "four"]
> let naturalNumbers = 1...Int.max
> let zipped = Array(zip(words, naturalNumbers))
> // zipped == [("one", 1), ("two", 2), ("three", 3), ("four", 4)]
> ```